# View not populate data after dropdown data selection

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I am work on MVC 5 and i fill a dropdown with state name of Country through ViewData and also in my view page i show the every state record. But i want, After selection of Dropdown value in view show only selected state value. this is my code that's not working

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index(int? id)
{
    ViewData["State"] = new SelectList(db.state, "state_id", "name");
    if (id!=null)
        return View(db.state.Where(x => x.state_id == id));
    else
        return View(db.state.ToList());
}
```

**View**

```
 @Html.DropDownList("ddlstate", (SelectList)ViewData["State"], "Select State", new { onchange = "Index(this.value);", @class = "form-control" })


    <table class="table" id="statedetails">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    State ID
                </th>
                <th>
                    State Name
                </th>
                <th>
                    City
                </th>
                <th>
                    Population
                </th>
                <th>
                    Education %
                </th> 
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.stateid)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.statename)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                         @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.city)

                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.population)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.eduction)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.offer_id }) |
                        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.offer_id }) |
                        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.offer_id })
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        }

    </table>
```

**javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Index(id) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("Index","State")",
            type: "POST",
            data: { "id": id }
        });
    }


</script>
```

Comment: Ajax calls stay on the same page, they don't redirect to a another page. You need to handle the data returned by the ajax call in the `success:` callback

Comment: You code also does not make sense. In your `Index` method you return a collection of `state` if the ID is null (and why if they are already displayed in the dropdown?), but return a collection of `offer` if `ID` is not null. They are 2 different types which means they cannot be used in the same view.

Comment: it means through ajax data, i create table row and bind them all.

Comment: Not making sense. Please post you view for the Index method

Comment: So it appears your view is initially displaying all the properties of `state`. What does `db.offers.Where(x => x.state_id == id)` return? (a collection of what type of object and what properties does that object have)? I suggest you post both `state` and `offer` models

Comment: Sorry @stephen by mistake i write offer. it's state.

Comment: OK, so initially you display all states. When you select a state from the dropdown, do you want to filter the table to show only rows which match the state ID? And can there be more than one row which matches the state ID?)

Comment: state_id this is auto genrated and another stateid has specific code. so, we have to filter data on the base of state_id

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand, but if your table initially shows all rows and you have a table cell displaying text for `stateid` (not sure if its `state_id` or `stateid` or they are 2 separate things) then there is no need to use ajax. You could just loop through each row of the table and use `show()` or `hide()` based on the drop down value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63387/discussion-between-anjyr-and-stephen-muecke).

Comment: I'm ready when you are